Remove pixels from a raster in QGIS
I have a raster map and I would remove isolated pixels or groups with less than 4 adjacent pixels. How can I do it in QGIS?

Majoritiy filter is probably the tool you need. See her for the concept behind it: https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/majority-filter.htm In QGIS, available through SAGA NextGEN provider Plugin (requires manual installation of SAGA): https://qgis-in-mineral-exploration.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/how_to/add_saga_next_gen.html

Would sieve suffice?

Documentation about sieve in https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_sieve.html and https://gdal.org/api/gdal_alg.html#_CPPv415GDALSieveFilter15GDALRasterBandH15GDALRasterBandH15GDALRasterBandHiiPPc16GDALProgressFuncPv
